# Is there a font that has more readable unicode arrows '→'?

Tags: unicode, font

I am trying to make my Agda code easier to read. The fonts I commonly used (Dejavu Sans Mono, Hack, Fira Code, Menlo) all has tiny arrow heads, which makes it very difficult to read. Is there a font (free would be a plus) that has more readable arrows?

[previously asked here](https://superuser.com/questions/1442370/is-there-a-font-that-has-more-readable-unicode-arrows-%E2%86%92?noredirect=1)

Comment: Have you tried **Consolas**?

Comment: Consolas is indeed better than those listed above! Thank you! But I wish the arrow head could be even bigger.

Comment: How about **SimSun**, **Archivo Narrow**, or **Overpass Mono**?

Comment: Thanks again for the super quick reply! Your suggestions lead to mefinding this awesome website https://www.wfonts.com and [fira-mono](https://www.wfonts.com/font/fira-mono) has the biggest arrow head I have seen so far.